# How to Disable 100% swipe of ViewPager in android

Tags: android

```
pager.BeginFakeDrag();

OR

pager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {           
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

> I have used these methods to 100% disable swipe but its still not
> Working perfectly.little swipe produce and you press again and again
> the next page of swipe shows.the problem is the swipe not 100%
> disabled .everytime you swipe 10% swipe to left or right done.How to
> Stop 100% swipe like raged page .I have implemented manullay viewpager
> like

```
 pager.SetCurrentITem(int i);
```

> Help me to resolve this error to stop swipe 100% thankyou.

Comment: make return `true` to `false`

Comment: Retrun False also not working

Comment: You need to make a custom Viewpager and use in `XML`.

Comment: Disbale working  but not 100% .little swipe  produce everytime when you swipe

Comment: You need to use `ViewPager2` since it's an improved version of `ViewPager`. It has a method `setUserInputEnabled` where you pass false and you won't be able to swipe.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] demonstrating "little swipe produce everytime"?   That linked question has worked for hundreds of people, and I'm also a bit perplexed how a `ViewPager` that _isn't receiving touch events_ could possibly be being swiped by touch.

Comment: (but also yes `ViewPager2` makes this much easier)